# Whats the cleanest/best way to implement Equals and GetHashCode on 3rd party types you don't have access to?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The problem is you have a 3rd party type e.g. ClassA below. I don't have access to the code and it doesn't implement Equals and GetHashCode therefore I need to write a wrapper class I think. The Equals and GetHashCode impls should use all the private member fields.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a shortcut or pattern I should be using?

Thanks

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int FieldA {get; set;}
    public double FieldB { get; set; }
    public string FieldC { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would inherit from ClassA and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

You will need to base your implementation on the public properties, since there is no way you have access to the private fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `ClassA` as a dictionary key, you can implement your own class that implement `IEqualityComparer<ClassA>`, and pass it to the constructor of the dictionary. This allows you to override the type's `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your own class from ClassA and then implement GetHashCode and Equals in it.

Answer (score 0):

As per Griver and Driis above - inherit or aggregate ClassA and implement Equals based on the a properties.

MSDN publishes some guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx)